# Installing Ubuntu on IBM S812L

Tags: ibm, ipmi

My old red hat enterprise server boot up OK then

After a while it become black screen.

And when I power down it using the server panel it shows my Linux powering down.. (terminating services)

Have no idea what's wrong... As I just took over this 4 year old server left unused in the rack and was ask to do something to it.

I am trying to have a fresh installation of Ubuntu on my IBM S812L server... Anyone has done that before canguide me?

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server, though there are others - https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-live-server.html, https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/serverguide.pdf  (3 of the 5 top choices in a startpage search).

Comment: Power8 is the same as AMD64 & ARM you'll note; only LinuxONE or z Systems have their own documentation.